# Show an underconstruction page during domain propogation

Tags: dns, nameservers

We changed our hosting provider yesterday and right seeing [THIS](http://eyaas.com) page. Is there any way, I can show an underconstruction page instead of this.

BTW, how much time does nameservers edit take ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are migrating your hosting (and nameserver), the best way to have never a site down is "to prepare" the second (new) server at the same time (for example, pick a under construction page in the index of the new server (that i presume now is just an ip address), then when the dns has migrated (and you are showing the under construction page) you can move all the site in the new server location and get back online).

The edit of the dns can take a range of time depending of ISP you use, in my experience (with www.switch.ch) take from 12 to 48 hours. Is not an exactly science ;)